# Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu 16.04: Open file directly will give wrong path

Tags: ubuntu, text-editors, ubuntu-16.04

When open file from inside Visual Studio Code, it works fine. But if go to the directory and double-click the file, Visual Studio Code will load wrong path

It should load

```
/home/apasajja/Desktop/untitled.html
```

But instead, it load:

```
/home/apasajja/file:/home/apasajja/Desktop/untitled.html
```

No matter what directory, Visual Studio Code will add `/home/apasajja/file:` in front of the path thus make it show blank content

I'm using:

- Visual Studio Code Version 1.8.1
- Ubuntu 16.04 x64

Comment: The same problem!